# How to set ActionBar logo to Text (TextView)?

Tags: java, android, android-actionbar, graphical-logo

I've been trying to make the ActionBar logo, or the Up button, a text instead of an image. `actionbar.setLogo();` accepts only a drawable resource. Inflating a layout with a `TextView` didn't do the trick.

Basically, what I'm trying to accomplish is this:

[image]

The first one is from the new DeskClock app from Android 4.2 and the second is from the Contacts app. I checked the code in GitHub but I couldn't find anything.

Comment: [Styled Action Bar](http://code.google.com/p/styled-action-bar/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an implementation of @CommonsWare's option #1, works perfectly.

```
TextView upTextView = (TextView) getLayoutInflater().inflate(
        R.layout.up_text, null);
upTextView.setText("CITIES");
upTextView.measure(0, 0);
upTextView.layout(0, 0, upTextView.getMeasuredWidth(), 
        upTextView.getMeasuredHeight());
Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(upTextView.getMeasuredWidth(),
        upTextView.getMeasuredHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
upTextView.draw(canvas);
BitmapDrawable bitmapDrawable = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), bitmap);
```

`R.layout.up_text`:

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingLeft="4dp"
    android:paddingRight="4dp"
    android:textColor="#f00"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />
```

Answer (score 5):

Off the cuff:

Option #1: Draw your text (`TextView` or directly) on a `Bitmap`-backed `Canvas`, and then supply a `BitmapDrawable` to `setLogo()`.

Option #2: Hide the icon and logo and use `setCustomView()` to have your caret image and your text.

Comment: I think option #2 has the disadvantage that you can't display a title, because the title is to the left of the custom view. But option #1 is perfect, see my answer.

Comment: @matthias: Your custom view is welcome to contain a title `TextView`, along with the caret and other text. That being said, I am glad that you have something working to your satisfaction.